# Laravel Как использовать переменные из другого файла

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно передать параметр `$table_name = 'server_1_users'` в файл User.php
как это могу сделать ? немного запутался...

**MainController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public $table_name = 'server_1_users';
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public $table;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->table = $table_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

вариантов много, например так

**MainController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public $table_name = 'server_1_users';

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $user = new User($this->table_name);
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public $table;

    public function __construct($table_name)
    {
      $this->table = $table_name;
    }
}
```

или так

**MainController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public static $table_name = 'server_1_users';
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public $table;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->table = MainController::$table_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо второй способ помог вот только теперь мне нужно $table_name указать в нутри функции а если указываю то пишет что он должен быть статичным как это решить?

Comment: Внутри какой функции?

Comment: при использовании `$user = new User($this->table_name);` получаю ошибку $table_name as non static

Comment: отредактировал второй вариант

Comment: Пример с переписыванием `__construct` модели является плохой практикой, т.к. переписывает стандартный. Сделай отдельный публичный метод.

Comment: @МаксимК  `parent::__construct();` справится с переопределением конструктора в классе наследника